# Running workflows on relationship entities

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm-2011, workflow

I'm trying to run a custom workflow on an entity that is in an N:N relationship with another entity. Here's what I mean, the table names are as follow

```
Entity 1's base table: ms_FolderBase
Entity 2's base table: ms_Folder_FileBase
```

But I can't find `ms_Folder_FileBase` anywhere in the default solution and when creating a custom workflow, I can't set the target entity to it. It seems like a "ghost" entity of some sort.

Is there something I'm missing ?

EDIT: `ms_Folder_FileBase` seems to be a relationship entity configured with "File" as "Other Entity". I'm still wondering it it's possible to launch a workflow on `ms_Folder_FileBase`

The reason I want to do this is that my workflow will be easier to handle. I'll have one "Folder" on the one hand, and then the instance of the workflow will be aware of which "type" of "File" I'm processing.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box you cannot run workflow against N:N relationships. Table that stores associations is, as you have described, "ghost" entity.

You can have a look at http://crm2011distributewf.codeplex.com/

Other option is to add plugin to Associate message and do your magic there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you have an example for the "other option" ?

Comment: for example here: http://rajeevpentyala.wordpress.com/2013/04/17/associatedisassociate-plugin-messages-in-crm/